# Slice ng-repeat in pagination Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hey I have one question about pagination. This code is useful when I load data from database e.g. list of users. But now I want to dynamically create inputs (for quiz questions) and use `$index` in `ng-repeat`.

There's a problem, however: because I use `slice` in pagination, `$index` is sliced too. In my example there are two items on the page, but if you create more than two you'll see the same numbers - 'Question 1' and 'Question 2' on all the pages.

How I can correctly set up `$index` in pagination? I would like that on first page will be 1,2 on second 3,4 etc.

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])

.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.currentPage = 2;
  $scope.itemsPerPage = 2; 
  $scope.questionQuiz = [];
  $scope.addQuizQuestion = function(){
    $scope.questionQuiz.push({});
    $scope.totalItems = $scope.questionQuiz.length;
  }
})
```

```css
a:hover
{
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="example.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <a class="input-group-addon" ng-click="addQuizQuestion()">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add question
  </a> 
  <div ng-repeat="question in questionQuiz.slice(((currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage), ((currentPage*itemsPerPage))) track by $index">
   <label><h3>Question {{$index + 1}}</h3></label>                      
   <input type="text" ng-model="input[$index]" class="form-control" placeholder="Write something...">
  </div> 
  <pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" class="pagination-sm text-center" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" previous-text="Prev" next-text="Next">     </pagination>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the number of items before the indexed one, like this:

```
<label><h3>Question {{$index + 1 + (currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage}}</h3></label>
```

Comment: could you help why if I check my checkbox and go to next page and back to previous my chceckbox are clear? Only first is checked?

Comment: It's not a good practice to merge two questions in one here at SO. Not only this messes up the history, it also confuses the readers (and remember, this site is a community first and foremost, this thread might turn out to be helpful to someone else). Why don't you create a separate question?